# "Command raised an exception: AttributeError 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'id'" when giving a set role

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Reaction Role bot with the ability to set the role given when reacted. I have tried:

```
verifyroleid = int(0)
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def set(ctx, *, roleid=None):
    em = discord.Embed(title="yBot  |  VERIFY")
    em.add_field(name="SUCCESS: ",value="Set {} as 'verify' role!".format(roleid))
    em.set_footer(text="© 2020 - Powered by yanuu ;k#2137")
    verifyroleid == roleid
    await ctx.send(embed=em)




@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def verify(ctx):
    em = discord.Embed(title="yBOT  |  VERIFY")
    em.add_field(name="REACT: ", value="React '✅' to this message to get verified!", inline=False)
    em.set_footer(text="© 2020 - Powered by yanuu ;k#2137")
    message = await ctx.send(embed=em)
    await message.add_reaction("✅")
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add")
    def check(reaction, user):
        return user != bot.user and str(reaction.emoji) in ["✅"]
    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add")
            if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
                role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=verifyroleid)
                await discord.Member.add_roles(user, role)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.delete()
            return
```

But it results in an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\macio\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users<..>\Documents\pythontest\diskord-test.py", line 99, in on_command_error
raise error
File "C:\Users<..>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users<..>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "C:\Users<..>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

How can I fix this?

Comment: It might have to do with the fact that the 8th line of your snippet is `verifyroleid == roleid`

Comment: It might, but I don't know the solution to it, what's the other way to describe 'verifyroleid' as 'roleid'  so the verify command recognizes the id?

Comment: A single `=` is an assignment operator, meaning that the value on the right gets assigned to the variable name on the left. `==` is an equality operator, meaning that it checks whether the value of the left side equals that of the right side. In this case you need an assignment operator, because you want to assign `roleid` to `verifyroleid`.